# CefSharp Chromium winforms web browser to get the text selected or gets the position of cursor in it

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, cefsharp

the existing functionality in winforms is as follows,

1. browser control to show html as shown in browser
2. RichTextBox control to show html content as text

first we show the big document in both controls, user selects the html content in RichTextBox, while he selects the content in RichTextBox, the corresponding text in web browser control will get scrolled using the properties of document x and y points of web browser control. after selecting the content, he clicks a button so we capture it as small document

Now we want to rewrite the same behavior with Cefsharp Chromium browser in place of winforms web browser. But cefSharp chromium browser doesn't have document class to get the same features of winforms web browser document class features.

Basically we want to show same content in chromium browser which is selected by user in RichTextBox wherever user's cursor in and vice versa. Please suggest me how can we do with chromium browser. we appreciate your help or suggestions.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE].

Comment: Please edit your original question and provide an example of the code you are trying to convert from using the WinForms built in browser.

Comment: Please provide an example of the code you are using currently with the built in web browser.

Comment: You can get the selected text via JavaScript using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#2-how-do-you-call-a-javascript-method-that-returns-a-result to capture an event in JavaScript see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/Frequently-asked-questions#JSEvent